# Commit via C# code - git

Tags: c#, git, asp.net-core, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I written .net core 2.0 web application. In My application I use git library: "LibGit2Sharp"

I have problem with commit - my application get request from external service and must get data via rest request after that create files and create commit added files. In Crone (5 minutes) I push data to git server.

If application have to many request git stop working... and I lost whole history (all files in git repo). (I save commit Id to get diff after)

My commit code:

```
if (flagHtml)
    Commands.Stage(repo, fileName + ".html");

if (flagDisplay)
    Commands.Stage(repo, fileName + ".json");

var author = new Signature(notification.userName, $"{notification.userName}@test.test", DateTime.Now);
var commit = repo.Commit($"Update asset: {notification.assetId} by {notification.userName}.", author, author, new CommitOptions { AllowEmptyCommit = true });
```

I calling this method in Mutex. Only one way to fix it what I find was type Sleep 1 second after commit (inside mutex). So It have time to process before next commit will come.

But I afraid it is wrong idea to do this because if I will get bigger file 1 second can be not enough.

Comment: Whatever you are doing, your current solution sounds like you have an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you use a Cron-job to push commits? Why do you run into race-conditions with a process like this? Why do you need a Sleep for something that shouzld clearly tell you when it's done?

Comment: Cron: because my application can retrieve thousands of requests per 10 second (one request - one commit) so push after each commit can be not possible - I decided to move it to cron and push data regularly (this is not problem - problem is with commit or staging) 
Sleep: Because my code complete commit but git process it longer I thing so sleep help with that (it's only hypothesis)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer My thoughts exactly, but also a bit of a Red Herring with the first problem! :D

Comment: @R.Prog `one request - one commit` ... Any thoughts on that ? This is `GIT` you know...

Comment: @R.Prog Then git is maybe not the right technology for something like this.

Comment: @Manfred Radlwimmer I need have file versioning and get diff.

Comment: @Pogrindis It means - I get 1 request from external source I have to crate 2 files and immediately create commit with those 2 files.

Comment: @R.Prog What do those *requests* do and what kind of files do you store? Maybe this is something a beefy SQL-Server would be able to handle more efficiently.

Comment: It is request with information - something changed so I download changes from external source save it in local disc and create commit. This files contains json/html

Comment: I can use MySql/Mongo as a databases

Comment: @R.Prog Like a Web-Scraper that keeps track of website changes?

Comment: Yes that keeps track of changes but this is not websites - but other data